# 500 internal server error .htaccess codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, url-rewriting

ı have a website that using codeigniter, it was working great, but ı need to format pc. ı installed windows 7 64 bit.

and then

ı pasted my project back to www directory and now ı get this error. ı dont change any code or something. ı just formatted my pc. .htaccess was working ı didnt change it.

ı am working on localhost, ı dont change any think and ı dont know why it happened. please help me ı have to solve it.

full error:

```
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, admin@localhost and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /blogna/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: 1. check windows firewall
2. remove and readd C.I.

Comment: check apache log for more details.

Comment: The error log will contain exact details for the error. What you see in the browser is deliberately vague to keep internal config details from leaking out.

Answer (score 4):

Use this to check to see if mod-rewrite is working.  If it is not working you will get an 404 page instead of internal server error 500

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /blogna/index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

The IfModule checks to see if the module is available.  You can find a wiki entry on mod-rewrite and codeigniter here http://codeigniter.com/wiki/mod_rewrite

If you see the 404 error you need to enable mod-rewrite.  If you still see the 500 error something else is wrong.

Comment: I tried many things like this but this was the only thing worked for me.... Big thanks. Can you please explain what you mean by <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

Comment: @Ruwantha It checks to see if the mod_rewrite module is loaded and in use by apache.  If apache does not have mod_rewrite enabled then display Error404

Comment: Then where as IfModule mod_rewrite.c is it should work... shan't ? Because if in my vhost <IfModule mod_rewrite.c> become true... but when it is not there it is not working

Answer (score 0):

ı found the solution, thank you guys.

if you want to use htaccess you have to enable it on wampserver.

servivec section.

Answer (score 0):

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```